# .closest .prev jquery not working to focus on the A tag above

Tags: jquery, css

Not sure why this isn't working but I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/m9uqdx5y/

```
<div class="sectionContent">
  <span class="open"><a>top</a></span>
  <span class="closeEditorLink"><a>bottom</a></span>
</div>

    var $preDiv = $('.closeEditorLink');
    $($preDiv).click(function () {
        $($preDiv).closest('.sectionContent a').focus();
    });
```

I just need to focus on that A tag above.

Comment: you don't have an anchor with the class `closeEditorLink`, it's a `span`

Comment: even if i take that out it still doesnt work

Comment: Your `$preDiv` is already a jquery object, so you don't need `$($preDiv)`, just `$preDiv.click`, `$preDiv.closest`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`.closeEditorLink` is not a child of `.sectionContent a`, so `.closest(".sectionContent a")` turns up nothing.

Try `.closest('.sectionContent').find('.open a').focus();` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try change your javascript code like this:

Jquery:

```
var preDiv = $('.closeEditorLink');
preDiv.on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.sectionContent a').focus();
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click', '.closeEditorLink', function() {
    $(this).parent().closest('a').focus();
});
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

**Write Like below**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var preDiv = $('.closeEditorLink');
  $(preDiv).click(function () {
     $($preDiv).closest('.sectionContent').find('a').focus();
  });
})
```